# Encoding in Spring-rest api

Tags: spring, rest, spring-rest

I have a rest end point where I send a json to the user . But there is a encoding problem with russian symbols

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@Transactional
public ResponseEntity<String> getOrder(@PathVariable String id, @RequestParam Map<String, String> params)
{

        String result = "{"id":"composite_order2","href":"/orderManagement/2.0/serviceOrder/composite_order2","state":"Acknowledged","orderDate":"2018-05-17T18:27:29+03:00","orderSpecification":{},"relatedParty":[{"role":"customer","name":"\" АГРО - СТАР \""}]}"
        return new ResponseEntity<>(result, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

While viewing on the browser , the JSON appers as

```
{"id":"composite_order2","href":"/orderManagement/2.0/serviceOrder/composite_order2","state":"Acknowledged","orderDate":"2018-05-17T18:27:29+03:00","orderSpecification":{},"relatedParty":[{"role":"customer","name":"\" ???? - ???? \""}]}
```

The russian symbols for name are replaced with ????-????
The ResponseEntry class is from SPring Framework
org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;

Comment: Have you tried `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE` ?

Comment: @Icaro Pinhole No , will try and update

Comment: Also, you don't have to return a String, you can return the actual object and use Jackson to serialize and deserialize it for you